# Pass variable of a function in the function call

Tags: php, function, variables

So I am writing this php function which reads a csv file and assigns every column to a variable. In the end it needs to calculate the mean of a row. I would like to pass the row (from which the mean has to calculated) in the parameters.

My question is how do I pass a variable **name** (including the dollar sign) of a variable of the function?

I've tried several things like:

- `function("$number")    //this just says the variable is undefined, which is true`
- Same as above, but without the quotes, does the same thing of course...
- `function("\$number")`

Comment: You're obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Need to show actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds something like [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). So, if you have a variable `$foo` you would pass it like this: `myfunc('foo');` Then `myfunc` might look something like this:

```
myfunc($var) {
  global $$var;
  // do stuff with $$var
}
```

You'd probably be better off just loading the columns into an array and looping over that in the function.

Comment: That is it! Thanks a lot. I searched quite a long time for this simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you need is a variable variable:

```
$some = 'foo';
$name = 'some';

echo $$name; //displays 'foo'
```